# on visualising roots of a five degree equation

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am maths undergrad and I have done Galois theory but I do not see why there should be no expression for finding roots of a five degree equation similar to Ferrari's solution or cubic solution.
I know the proof of Abel-Ruffini theorem, but it just feels like reading a novel.
I don't get a feel of the theorem.
Is there any easier way to visualize it or wrap my head around it?
Something that would make sense to a high school student ?